# webbrowser control modal dialog

Tags: c#, winforms-to-web

I am using WebBrowserControl in winforms to automate a data entry form.  This website opens a new dialog window using ShowModalDialog and puts all the form fields in that new dialog window.  How can I access that modal dialog window's contents from my winforms code and want to populate fields.  When I access the webbrowser's document it shows the main document not the opened dialog window.  Is there any way to access the opened dialog's document?  I tried to inject javascript to access contents but the javascript is blocked till the modal dialog is open.

Answer (score 0):

I used WatiN and it could handle the modal dialogs.  WatiN also handles the cross domain iframe access